# Import.io some crawlers don't have the button for crawl locally

Tags: import.io

I was creating some crawlers using import.io however seems like for some of them the option for run locally is not showing. Anyone knows why they dont have the run from local button or how i can make to put in the crawlers?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't see the option to run the crawler [Remotely or locally] then it means that your crawler is already running locally only.

Answer (score 0):

When you save a crawler, import.io does a few checks to see if it can be run remotely on our servers, in some cases this increases chances of crawlers working as the servers do additional processing.

If those check fail, then the crawler can only run locally and therefore your crawler will be run locally be default.